# Transistor PWM Switch H-Bridge

Tags: design, schematics, h-bridge, wiring

*Update from old post*

I have made a completely different design and was wondering if you guys could take a look.

Schematics: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPSzO.jpg

Description: Figure 1 is a charge pump, boosting the 6V to around 21-22V which is then sent to Figure 4, which is a optocouple (http://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/IX3180.pdf/$file/IX3180.pdf) which is switched on by inputs from the micro controller (Figure 7) controlling the ground signal and the anode is controlled by Figure 5, a atmega328p that is programmed to read a i2c signal and generated a specified pwm signal. This 21-22V signal is then directed to the H-Bridge which controls the speed, forward and reverse of the motor.

Comment: You really need to ask specific questions. However, your last sentence is incorrect, as Q6 is a P-channel FET, and will therefor be ON when Q13 pulls to ground.

Comment: Isn't there a free simulator somewhere you can access and learn to use instead of asking ignominious questions?

Comment: Why do your voltage regulators look like SCRs?

Comment: It had the correct footprint so i just used it. As for the simulator, I can't find a simulator that has optocouples in it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming VCC5 is 5V and VCC12 is 12V, it won't work because the PMOS FETs won't turn off. To turn off they need +12V on the Gate, but the 555 only puts out +4V (leaving 8V on the Gate).

Another potential problem is that you don't have any 'dead time' when switching between the upper and lower FET. During the transition both FETs will be on and a large 'shoot-through' current will pass through them, directly from +12V to ground. If you only apply PWM to the lower FET and leave the upper FET turned off then you won't have this problem.

Your method of suppressing PWM on one side is not good because it sucks an extra 50mA out of the 555, which lowers the Gate drive voltage and slows down the FET's switching speed.

Comment: whenever I see a 555, I just assume the schematic is riddled with errors. Not because there is anything fundamentally wrong with the 555, but people find it easy to use.